# Issue In Changing Column Names using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

It's my first question on Stack Overflow; I am facing a problem in changing column names.

I have a table `INS_Sink` with columns like

```
INS2017, INS2018, INS2019, INS2020
```

Now I need to change the existing column names like this:

```
INS2017 to INS CY-3,
INS2018 to INS CY-2,
INS2019 to INS CY-1,
INS2020 to INS CY,
```

where `CY = CurrentYear`.

I need to change all the columns dynamically like the above mentioned and the column names should be changed automatically when the year gets changed like in the year 2021, INS2020 should become INS CY-1..

Can anyone help me how to achieve this and I don't want to alter my columns here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not do this.  The underlying table should reflect the correct data.

Second, you should not use names like `INS CY-1`.  Such a name needs to be escaped.  Instead, you should use `INS_CY_1`.  That is cleaner.

Next, you have a problem with your data model.  You should be storing the data as:

```
YEAR     INSVALUE
2017     ?
2018     ?
```

Of course, you might have other columns that you haven't specified.

With this data structure, it is easy to create a view that does what you want.  Say, the current year is found using `YEAR(GETDATE())`.  Then:

```
select sum(case when t.year = v.yyyy then t.insvalue end) as ins_cy,
       sum(case when t.year = v.yyyy - 1 then t.insvalue end) as ins_cy_1,
       sum(case when t.year = v.yyyy then t.insvalue end) as ins_cy_2
from t cross join
     (values (year(getdate())) v(yyyy);
```

You can continue this logic for however many years you want to go back in time.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,
Here the columns are containing the Float Values and if i try to retrieve the data from that table using select * from INS_Sink, the columns should automatically display like as i mentioned above with data present in those columns. Also, other columns are present in the table.
Can I achieve this with the Stored Proc?

Comment: Also, here in this case with the above mentioned code, iam not getting the data present in respective columns instead Getting nulls.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to get the data in CY-xyz columns then it might be better to create a view and adjust the view when needed (you could use both the view and the table for DML operations).

```
create table dbo.INS_Sink_test
(
id int identity(1,1) constraint pk_id_ins_sink_test primary key clustered,
col1 int,
col2 int,
INS2010 int,
INS2011 int,
INS2012 int,
INS2013 int,
INS2014 int,
INS2015 int,
INS2016 int,
INS2017 int,
INS2018 int,
INS2019 int,
INS2020 int
)
go
insert into dbo.INS_Sink_test
(
    col1, col2, INS2010, INS2011, INS2012, INS2013, INS2014, INS2015, INS2016, INS2017, INS2018, INS2019, INS2020
)
values
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4)
go

--create/adjust a view

declare @year smallint = year(getdate());

newyear:

declare @colssql nvarchar(max) = N'';
select @colssql = @colssql + N',' + quotename(name) + ' as ' + quotename(newcolname)
from
(
select column_id,
    name,
    case when name like 'INS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 'CY' + isnull(cast(nullif(cast(replace(name, 'INS', '') as smallint)-@year, 0) as sysname), '')
        else name
    end as newcolname
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('dbo.INS_Sink_test')
) as a
order by column_id;

declare @viewsql nvarchar(max) = N'view dbo.v_INS_Sink_test
as
select 
'  + stuff(@colssql, 1, 1, N'') + N'
from dbo.INS_Sink_test
';

select @viewsql = case when object_id('dbo.v_INS_Sink_test') is null then N'create' else N'alter' end + N' ' + @viewsql ;
--print @viewsql
exec(@viewsql);
--dont forget to refresh other views that depend on v_ins_sink_test
--exec sp_refreshview 'dbo.view_xyz';
exec sp_refreshview 'dbo.v_INS_Sink_test';


select @year as theyear;
select *
from dbo.INS_Sink_test;

select *
from dbo.v_INS_Sink_test;


if @year = 2021
begin
    --cleanup
    if object_id('dbo.INS_Sink_test') is not null
    begin
        drop table dbo.INS_Sink_test;
    end 

    if object_id('dbo.v_INS_Sink_test') is not null
    begin
        drop view dbo.v_INS_Sink_test;
    end 

    return;
end

--i know what you did in 2021..
select @year = 2021;
goto newyear
--cleanup
/*
if object_id('dbo.INS_Sink_test') is not null
begin
    drop table dbo.INS_Sink_test;
end 

if object_id('dbo.v_INS_Sink_test') is not null
begin
    drop view dbo.v_INS_Sink_test;
end 
*/
```

For changing the column names of the table:

```
create table dbo.INS_Sink_test
(
id int identity(1,1) constraint pk_id_ins_sink_test primary key clustered,
col1 int,
col2 int,
INS2010 int,
INS2011 int,
INS2012 int,
INS2013 int,
INS2014 int,
INS2015 int,
INS2016 int,
INS2017 int,
INS2018 int,
INS2019 int,
INS2020 int
)
go
insert into dbo.INS_Sink_test
(
    col1, col2, INS2010, INS2011, INS2012, INS2013, INS2014, INS2015, INS2016, INS2017, INS2018, INS2019, INS2020
)
values
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4)
go

select *
from dbo.INS_Sink_test
go

--rename columns
declare @year smallint = year(getdate());
declare @renamecolssql nvarchar(max) = N'';
select @renamecolssql = @renamecolssql + N'exec sp_rename '''  + quotename(object_schema_name(object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(name) + ''', '+ quotename(newcolname) + '; '
from
(
select 
    object_id,
    column_id,
    name,
  'INS CY' + isnull(cast(nullif(cast(replace(name, 'INS', '') as smallint)-@year, 0) as sysname), '') as  newcolname
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('dbo.INS_Sink_test') --<-- change the name of the table
and name like 'INS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
) as a
order by column_id;

exec(@renamecolssql);
go

select *
from dbo.INS_Sink_test
go

--cleanup
drop table dbo.INS_Sink_test
go
```

Comment: Thanks mate, here i dont need to create a new table. I just want to update  the existing columns of a table like as mentioned above.

Comment: its frustrating actually, i dont know how to get it because i also dont need to alter the existing columns and it has to be changed automatically when the year gets changed

Comment: answer edited, added a script to change the column names of the table